# Different syntax of defining promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I am learning promise of JavaScript. There is one thing in this [code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Add-in-JS-SheetSwitcher/blob/master/Text%20Editor/Home.js) that puzzles me:

From Line 42, `return ctx.sync();` is followed by `})`, then `.then(function() {`.

```
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        // Create a proxy object for the worksheets collection
        var worksheets = ctx.workbook.worksheets;

        // Add 14 sheets to the workbook
        for (var i = 2; i <= 15; i++) {
            // Queue commands to add new sheets to the workbook
            worksheets.add("Sheet" + i);
        }

        //Disable the button
        $('#add-sheets').prop('disabled', true);


        //Run the queued-up commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion
        return ctx.sync();

    })
    .then(function () {
        // Now that we have sheets, create buttons for each sheet
        // in the taskpane to enable switching
        createSheetButtons();
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // Always be sure to catch any accumulated errors that bubble up from the Excel.run execution
        app.showNotification("Error: " + error);
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
```

However, from Line 75, `return ctx.sync()` is followed directly by then `.then(function() {`.

```
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        // Create a proxy object for the worksheets collection 
        var worksheets = ctx.workbook.worksheets;

        // Queue a command to load the name property of each worksheet
        worksheets.load("name");

        //Run the queued-up commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion
        return ctx.sync()
            .then(function () {
                //create a button for each sheet in the task pane
                for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.items.length; i++) {
                    var buttonName = worksheets.items[i].name;
                    var $input = $('<input type="button" class="ms-Button" value=' + buttonName + '>');
                    $input.appendTo($("#buttons-div"));
                    // Add a click event handler for the button
                    (function (buttonName) {
                        $input.click(function (e) {
                            makeActiveSheet(buttonName);
                        });
                    })(buttonName);
                }
            });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // Always be sure to catch any accumulated errors that bubble up from the Excel.run execution
        app.showNotification("Error: " + error);
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
```

Could anyone tell me if this subtlety of syntax makes any difference between the definitions of these two promises?

Comment: What's wrong with my question? is it too easy?

Comment: It seems you have outsourced data critical for the understanding of your question. Please remember to provide all necessary data (code, configuration data, exception name ...) in **the question itself**. If the link dies or changes your question will lose most if not all of its meaning! You may be interested in reading the [help], particularly [ask] and what is a [mcve].

Comment: SoftTimur: Have a good look at the indentation of the code you linked.

Comment: Because one is returning a promise and one is using the returned promise.

Comment: @SoftTimur: One line of code is returning a promise by itself, the other line is returning a promise with a call to `.then()` added to it.  `.then()` acts as a "callback" to be invoked after the asynchronous operation completes.  So the first line is basically saying "here's an asynchronous operation", the second is saying "here's an asynchronous operation, and a follow-up operation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both functions (`.run()` and `.sync()`) ostensibly return promises, the completion for each one is just being captured in different places, the syntax is the same.

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
            // Create a proxy object for the worksheets collection
            var worksheets = ctx.workbook.worksheets;

            // Add 14 sheets to the workbook
            for (var i = 2; i <= 15; i++) {
                // Queue commands to add new sheets to the workbook
                worksheets.add("Sheet" + i);
            }

            //Disable the button
            $('#add-sheets').prop('disabled', true);


            //Run the queued-up commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion
            return ctx.sync();

        })
        .then(function () {
            // Now that we have sheets, create buttons for each sheet
            // in the taskpane to enable switching
            createSheetButtons();
        })
```

That will run `.then()` on the promise returned from `.run()` whereas in

```
return ctx.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    //create a button for each sheet in the task pane
                    for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.items.length; i++) {
                        var buttonName = worksheets.items[i].name;
                        var $input = $('<input type="button" class="ms-Button" value=' + buttonName + '>');
                        $input.appendTo($("#buttons-div"));
                        // Add a click event handler for the button
                        (function (buttonName) {
                            $input.click(function (e) {
                                makeActiveSheet(buttonName);
                            });
                        })(buttonName);
                    }
                });
```

`.then()` is being run on the promise returned from `.sync()`